# replacing string in python

Tags: python, c, string, parsing, replace

I have the following sequences in C code:

```
variable == T_CONSTANT
```

or

```
variable != T_CONSTANT
```

Using Python, how can I replace these by `SOME_MACRO(variable)` or `!SOME_MACRO(variable)`, respectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple and error-prone method is to use regular expressions:

```
>>> s = "a == T_CONSTANT"
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r"(\w+)\s*==\s*T_CONSTANT", r"SOME_MACRO(\1)", s)
'SOME_MACRO(a)'
```

A similar regex can be used for the `!=` part.

Comment: Thanks can you give an explanation ?

Comment: @ABRami: This is very basic stuff. You can use the [documentation of the `re` module](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) as a starting point for regular expressions in Python. If you have specific questions, go ahead and ask :)

Comment: in your answer there is (r what is it stand for i have not see documentation about it

Comment: @ABRami: It's a [raw string](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals). Why using these is sensible in the context of regular expressions is explained in the third paragraph of the linked documentation.

Comment: understood what you meant i am new in this sorry

Answer (score 0):

OK, I know you've already accepted the other answer. However, I just couldn't help but throw this out because your problem is one that often comes up and regular expressions may not always be suitable.

This chunk of code defines a tiny limited non-recursive [Parsing Expression Grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar) which allows you to describe what you're searching for in terms of a series of compiled regular expressions, alternatives (tuples of different matching strings) and plain strings. This format can be more convenient than a regular expression for a computer language because it looks similar to the formal specifications of the language's syntax. Basically, `[varname, ("==", "!="), "T_CONSTANT"]` describes what you're looking for, and the `action()` function describes what you want to do when you find it.

I've included a corpus of example "C" code to demonstrate the parser.

```
import re

# The @match()@ function takes a parsing specification and a list of
# words and tries to match them together. It will accept compiled
# regular expressions, lists of strings or plain strings. 

__matcher = re.compile("x") # Dummy for testing spec elements.
def match(spec, words):
    if len(spec) > len(words): return False

    for i in range(len(spec)):
        if   type(__matcher) is type(spec[i]):
            if not spec[i].match(words[i]): return False
        elif type(()) is type(spec[i]):
            if words[i] not in spec[i]: return False
        else:
            if words[i] != spec[i]: return False

    return True

# @parse()@ takes a parsing specification, an action to execute if the
# spec matches and the text to parse. There can be multiple matches in
# the text. It splits and rejoins on spaces. A better tokenisation
# method is left to the reader...

def parse(spec, action, text):
    words = text.strip().split() 

    n = len(spec)
    out = []
    while(words):
        if match(spec, words[:n+1]): out.append(action(words[:n+1])); words = words[n:]
        else: out.append(words[0]); words = words[1:]

    return " ".join(out)

# This code is only executed if this file is run standalone (so you
# can use the above as a library module...)

if "__main__" == __name__:
    # This is a chunk of bogus C code to demonstrate the parser with:

    corpus = """\
/* This is a dummy. */
variable == T_CONSTANT
variable != T_CONSTANT
/* Prefix! */ variable != T_CONSTANT
variable == T_CONSTANT /* This is a test. */
variable != T_CONSTANT ; variable == T_CONSTANT /* Note contrived placement of semi. */
x = 9 + g;
"""

    # This compiled regular expression defines a legal C/++ variable
    # name. Note "^" and "$" guards to make sure the full token is matched.
    varname = re.compile("^[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*$")

    # This is the parsing spec, which describes the kind of expression
    # we're searching for.
    spec = [varname, ("==", "!="), "T_CONSTANT"]

    # The @action()@ function describes what to do when we have a match.
    def action(words):
        if "!=" == words[1]: return "!SOME_MACRO(%s)" % words[0]
        else:                return "SOME_MACRO(%s)"  % words[0]

    # Process the corpus line by line, applying the parser to each line.
    for line in corpus.split("\n"): print parse(spec, action, line)
```

Here's the result if you run it:

```
/* This is a dummy. */
SOME_MACRO(variable)
!SOME_MACRO(variable)
/* Prefix! */ !SOME_MACRO(variable)
SOME_MACRO(variable) /* This is a test. */
!SOME_MACRO(variable) ; SOME_MACRO(variable) /* Note contrived placement of semi. */
x = 9 + g;
```

Oh well, I had fun! ; - )

Comment: I don't see how this would be more robust than the simple regex version? After all, it doesn't use a C parser as well, so it would make the same mistakes, for example if the macro is inside a comment or something. What you're parsing here is a regular grammar (Chomsky-3), so you should use a ... regular expression.